# How to sum two variables: constant and iterated in text input's "name"?

Tags: php, jquery, variables, iterated-function

I have a function:

```
<?php $max = 5; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    var scntDiv = $('#div');
    var i = $('#div p').size() + 2;
    var x = <?php echo $max;?>;
    var a = 0;
    $('#add').click (function() {
        $('<p><input type="text" id="" name="field['+a+'][0]" value="" placeholder="" /><a href="#" id="delete">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        a++;
        return false;
    });
    $('#delete').live('click',function() {
        if( i > 2 ) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see `var x` is constant and `var a` iterates in every click of `add` button. How to make these two variables sum each other with every iteration and to replace `+a+` in `name="field['+a+'][0]"`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you, but, why don't you init `var a = x;` ? (instead `var a = 0;`)

Comment: What do you mean by "sum each other"? Something like `var b = a + x;`?

Comment: @Roberto Sánchez - you're right! I don't know why I didn't think about it, I must have a brainstorm :/ Thank you!! BTW, How to close this question as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to extract it from comments, the easiest solution in this case would be:

Change:

```
var a = 0;
```

By

```
var a = x;
```

Comment: Like I said, I must have a brainstorm, a cup of coffee will do...! Thanks again.